# how to replace ( /" or /') to ( " or ') from the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

how to replace ( /" or /') to ( " or ') from the string in javascript. I am referring the content inside the braces. Could anyone give me regular expression for that. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use one regular expression to replace both:

```
str = str.replace(/\/(['"])/g, '$1');
```

Comment: +1 This is cool. I need to use backreferences more in my regexes :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string.replace(/\/"/g, "\"").replace(/\/'/g, "'");
```